# Dynamically, naming form elements in PHP

Tags: php, forms

I wil create a simple program that is somewhat similar to xampp phpmyadmin wherein the creation of database, creation of table structure is dynamic using forms. I tried to make their names dynamic so that i could loop them.

```
<?php $b =1; ?>

Field:<input name="field$b" type="text" /></br>
```

When i submit the form, the value of the form is null. Here's the code after the sumbitting of form

```
    $a = 1;

    $tblField = $_POST['field$a'];

    echo "field name : ".$tblField;
```

The output is

```
field name :
```

I'm not sure if what i did is right, in using a variable in the name of forms. but that is the only way i think i could do so that i could make the creation of table columns dynamic..

Comment: Is this the actual code? Because you can't use a PHP variable without opening PHP tags.

Comment: <input name="field<?php echo $b ?>" type="text" />

Comment: try to use Double Quote, but it is a strange way to do it.

Comment: better to store filedname in tables as it is dynamic, it will be beneficial for you in future enhancement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the `$` doing in `Field:<input name="field$b" type="text" /></br>` ?? If you are going to include the dollar sign `$` in your input name's field, then the whole code must be encapsulated in the php tags.

like this: `<?= 'Field:<input name="field$b" type="text" /></br>'; ?>` otherwise, it won't work

Comment: `<?= ?>` should always be avoided. `<?php echo ?>` is the way to go

Answer (score 3):

Un-escaped variables inside single quota will be treated as text:

```
$tblField = $_POST['field$a'];
```

To:

```
$tblField = $_POST["field$a"];
```

See php NoOb's answer also

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
<?php  $b =1;  
echo "Field:<input name=\"field$b\" type=\"text\" /></br>"; 
?>
```

?

Answer (score 2):

It's seems like you forgot to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
$_POST["field$a"];
```

instead of

```
$_POST['field$a'];
```